# Loader constraint violation issue with javax/management/MBeanServer

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jmx

I'm trying to migrate application from JBoss-4.0.4.GA to wildfly-10.1.0.Final. I have an issue with JMX.

During the start-up of application, I'm getting the following:

```
10:58:02,689 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 90) Failed to define class javax.management.MBeanServer in Module "com.xor.genesis:main" from local module loader @1c2c22f3 (finder: local module finder @18e8568 (roots: /home/user/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules,/home/user/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link javax/management/MBeanServer (Module "com.xor.genesis:main" from local module loader @1c2c22f3 (finder: local module finder @18e8568 (roots: /home/chaos1/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules,/home/chaos1/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base))): loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at com.xor.genesis.core.jmx.framework.ApplicationMBeanManager.registerMBean(ApplicationMBeanManager.java:37)
    at com.xor.genesis.cgo.listeners.CGOApplicationListener.registerApplicationLogger(CGOApplicationListener.java:161)
    at com.xor.genesis.cgo.listeners.CGOApplicationListener.initMBeans(CGOApplicationListener.java:112)
    at com.xor.genesis.cgo.listeners.CGOApplicationListener.contextInitialized(CGOApplicationListener.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

To be more precise in code level the following line is producing the exception above:

```
MBeanServer server = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
```

I created own module with list of needed jars. I didn't modify client libraries inside the wildfly.

Do you have any ideas how I can manage this problem?

Thanks,
Anatoly

Comment: Seems like is related to existence duplicates for MBeanServer.class in class path.

Answer (score 0):

This is the interesting part of the error message:

> loader constraint violation: loader (instance of
>   org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for
>   a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer" at

The underlying problem is explained [here](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.fr/2009/03/javalanglinkageerror-loader-constraint.html) in more detail. This article concludes:

> In simple words, a linkage error can occur if two different classes
>   interact with each other, and in this interaction the classes refer to
>   types with the same symbolic name but with different class objects.

The different class objects stem from the fact the classes are loaded through different class loaders, as each class is identified by its FQN and(!) the class loader it is loaded through.

Please check that you don't have multiple instances of javax/management/MBeanServer in your classpath (in the modules directory of the Wildfly/JBoss or even in your deployment).